# Navigate from LWC to LWC (managed)

Tags: lightning-web-components, navigationmixin.navigate, lightningnavigation

I have an issue when navigating from LWC to another inside a managed package. My code is:

```
           this.instanceId = event.target.name;
           var compDefinition = {
               componentDef: "c:instanceDetail",
               attributes: {
                   instanceId: this.instanceId
               }
           };
   
           var encodedCompDef = btoa(JSON.stringify(compDefinition));
           this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
               type: 'standard__webPage',
               attributes: {
                   url: '/one/one.app#' + encodedCompDef
               }
           });
```

This code works properly in my partner org, but it doesn't work when I generate a beta and install in other Org, it doesn't work.

I have tried to add the namespace in the componentDef variable like componentDef: c:myNamespace__instanceDetail" or componentDef: c:myNamespace:instanceDetail" but I have no idea why is working in the partner org and when the package is generated isn't.

Could someone help me giving some ideas??

Thank you!

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Would love a helpful response.